# How to download images from a website without the 'img' tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Recently I've been trying to learn how to webscrape in order to download all the images from my school directory. However, within the elements they are not storing the images under the img tag and instead have them ALL under this: background-image: url("/common/pages/GalleryPhoto.aspx?photoId=323070&width=180&height=180");

Anyway to bypass this??

Here is current code that will download images off of a targeted website

```
import os, requests, bsf n4, webbrowser, random 
 
url = 'https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/staff_directory' 
  
res = requests.get(url)
try: 
    res.raise_for_status() 
except Exception as exc: 
    print('Sorry an error occured:', exc) 
 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
element = soup.select('background-image') 
 
for i in range(len(element)): 
    url = element[i].get('img') 
    name = random.randrange(1, 25) 
    file = open(str(name) + '.jpg', 'wb') 
    res = requests.get(url) 
    for chunk in res.iter_content(10000): 
        file.write(chunk) 
    file.close() 
 
print('done')
```

Comment: You'll want to look at those tags' `style` attributes and parse out the image URL from there.

Comment: You will get only the first 10 images with this method. You’d better use a proper web scraping tool (wget, SiteSucker...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the internal API this site is using to get the data including the image URL. It first gets the list of staff groups using the `/settings` endpoint then calls the `/Search` api with all the groupID

The flow is the following :

- get the `portletInstanceId` value from a div tag with attribute `data-portlet-instance-id`
- call the settings api and get the groups ID:

  ```
  POST https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/Common/controls/StaffDirectory/ws/StaffDirectoryWS.asmx/Settings
  ```
- call the search api with pagination parameter, you can choose how many people you want to request and the number per page :

  ```
  POST https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/Common/controls/StaffDirectory/ws/StaffDirectoryWS.asmx/Search
  ```

The following script get the 20 first people and put the result in a pandas DataFrame:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/staff_directory")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

portletInstanceId = soup.select('div[data-portlet-instance-id].staffDirectoryComponent')[0]["data-portlet-instance-id"]

r = requests.post("https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/Common/controls/StaffDirectory/ws/StaffDirectoryWS.asmx/Settings",
    json = { "portletInstanceId": portletInstanceId })

groupIds = [t["groupID"] for t in r.json()["d"]["groups"]]
print(groupIds)

payload = {
    "firstRecord": 0,
    "groupIds": groupIds,
    "lastRecord": 20,
    "portletInstanceId": portletInstanceId,
    "searchByJobTitle": True,
    "searchTerm": "",
    "sortOrder": "LastName,FirstName ASC"
}

r = requests.post("https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/Common/controls/StaffDirectory/ws/StaffDirectoryWS.asmx/Search",
    json = payload)

results = r.json()["d"]["results"]

#add image url based on userID
for t in results:
    t["imageURL"] = f'https://jhs.lsc.k12.in.us/{t["imageURL"]}' if t["imageURL"] else ''
 
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

#whole data
print(df)

#only image url
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 400):
    print(df["imageURL"])
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/64627164)

You need to update `firstRecord` and `lastRecord` fields accordingly